# Wordpress ACF auto p overpopulating text field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm migrating custom wordpress templates over from an old site to a new site. In the new site one of my older templates using ACF Repeater is generating unnecessary < p > breaks between each element in my echo. Here's the source code:

```
<?php
 if( have_rows('features_list') ):
  $i=0;
   while ( have_rows('features_list') ) : the_row();
    echo '<p><span class="purple">+ </span>' .    get_sub_field('feature_item') . '</p>';
   $i++;
  endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

The rendered HTML comes out to:

```
<p>
 <span class="purple">+ </span>
</p>
<p>Text Content Text Content</p>
```

What I need it to render as and what it was in my old template is:

```
<p><span class="purple">+ </span> Text Content Text Content</p>
```

Im suspecting that Wordpress is wrapping my get_sub_field() in a < p > and therefore is closing the < span > around a < p > because of the wpautop() function. Im running Wordpress 4.5.3 and seeing this.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The 3rd code example I gave is what I need the PHP to render as: <p><span class="purple">+ </span> Text Content Text Content</p>

Comment: I should also note that the Custom Field is a "text" not a WYSIWYG.

Comment: Did you try `get_sub_field('feature_item', false)`? The documentation said the second parameter is for formatting which defaults to `true`. So maybe setting it false would just give you the raw data.

Comment: Nice, I see that now. I actually found that in the Custom Field dashboard under my sub-field there was a selector where I can specify formatting. It was by default set to "Automatically add paragraphs" and after changing the field to "None" it solved my issue. Thanks for the help, I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved. The solution was in the Custom Fields dashboard within the specific subfield. There is an option for "New Lines" conditional formatting and by default it was set to "Automatically add paragraphs". I switched it to "none" and this fixed the problem.

Thanks